# Nested loop for triangular matrix in C++

Tags: c++

Please can someone explain why I am getting 7 at the last iteration of the loops instead of 6?
It this a problem of my loops structure or the compilator needs an additional information?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int p = 4;
int i, j, k;
      for(i=0; i<(p-1); i++){
         for(j=(i+1); j<p; j++){

               cout << "i = " << i << " j = " << j << endl;
               k = i * (p - (i+1)/2) + j - i;
               cout << " k = " << k << endl;

         }
      }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

> ```
> i = 0 j = 1
> k = 1
> i = 0 j = 2
> k = 2
> i = 0 j = 3
> k = 3
> i = 1 j = 2
> k = 4
> i = 1 j = 3
> k = 5
> i = 2 j = 3
> k = 7
> ```

Comment: You did a good job showing the values of your variables, which could allow greater simplification of your code. Basically, you are asking why the expression `(2 * (4 - (2+1)/2) + 3 - 2)` evaluates to `7`, which could be demonstrated more simply by `int main()
{
 std::cout << (2 * (4 - (2+1)/2) + 3 - 2) << std::endl;
}`. No need to complicate things by having loops. (A good addition, though, would be an explanation of why you think this expression should evaluate to `6`. Maybe pick out individual sub-expressions to further narrow the misunderstanding.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic algebra with integer division using: `i = 2 j = 3`

Let's compute your line of code:

```
k = i * (p - (i+1)/2) + j - i
```

Breaking it down:

```
k = i * (p - (i+1)/2) + j - i

k = 2 * (4 - (2+1)/2) + 3 - 2

k = 2 * (4 - 3/2) + 3 - 2

k = 2 * (4 - 1) + 3 - 2

k = 2 * 3 + 1

k = 6 + 1

k = 7
```

For what's it's worth, each `+1` increment on `j` results in a `+1` increment on `k`.  But that same can't be said for `i`, which is a multiplication factor in that equation. That last iteration of your code sees `i` increment from `1` to `2`.